# How can I set readonly field without duplicating code when base class has constructor overloads?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Base(BaseArgA avalue)
    {
    }
    public Base(BaseArgB bvalue)
    {
    }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    private readonly FooArg _fooval;
    
    public Foo(FooArg fooval,BaseArgA aval) : base(aval)
    {
        // init code for fooval
    }
    public Foo(FooArg fooval, BaseArgB bval) : base(bval)
    {
        // duplicate init code for fooval
    }
}
```

Here I end up duplicating the code for ***fooval*** in the derived class. Since _fooval is readonly, it cannot be refactored into a non-constructor method.

My first thought was that constructor chaining would help me. But even if I could chain a constructor taking only a FooArg and invoke it with ***: this(fooval)***, the new constructor would not be able to satisfy the constructor of Base class and thus be an invalid constructor.

I can of course remove the word "readonly" as a workaround, but I feel that this should have a better solution.

Comment: Do `BaseArgA` and `BaseArgB` implement a common interface? Like some `IBaseArg` ?

Comment: could use optional parameters to merge two constructors into one and do some extra check if both parameters are provided at the same time

Comment: When TSHTF: Do have the option to make changes to `Base`?

Comment: @Fildor No, regretfully they don't.

Comment: @user7313094 You mean in the base class? That could work. It would be an undesired change in the base class, so if that is the only solution, then I think I will rather pay the price of removing "readonly" in the Foo class and making a private method.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes, I can keep the readonly if I keep only the assignment in each constructor and refactor out the rest. It is undesirable to duplicate this if there are multiple constructors and multiple readonly fields, but for very small instances it is about the same "cost" as removing readonly. So it is a possibility, yes.

Comment: I'm looking at a solution, but for now I'd rather take the duplicate road instead, as a `private readonly` field is usually a big "no-touchy"!

Comment: @DavideVitali Thank you. Indeed. Base class shouldn't be modified to feature a "catch-all" constructor with tons of optionables. Neither should one need to forego the readonly field. Nor should the constructors need to duplicate code, so I'm basically at a "lesser evil" unless there is a language trick or pattern that eludes me.